# List files in tar.gz file from SFTP server using phpseclib without downloading it

Tags: php, gzip, sftp, tar, phpseclib

I am working with SFTP server. How can I view the list of files in .tar.gz (5 GB size) file without downloading and extracting it? I am using phpsiclib1.0.7 for that. 
I am successfully login on SFTP server and list all the directories. For that I have used below code.

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('sftp.tripadvisor.com');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
  exit('Login Failed');
} else {
  $current_dir= $sftp->nlist();
  $sftp->nlist('drop/listings/');
}
?>
```

Comment: What did you try so far ? can you provide your code ? see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What does it mean "read"? Cannot you just download it and process it locally? Or do you need/want to do something more fancy? Please explain!

Comment: file size is 5 GB. so I don't want to download. just need to read file name.

Comment: And where does your question say that? Edit it! And explain in more details, what does "read file name" mean.

Comment: Again, what does it mean *"get filename"*? What filename?

Comment: a tar file doesn't have a directory listing section, so you need to scan through the whole file to get a listing of the files inside, and because of the fact that the tar file is stored with gzip, you cannot skip over parts in the file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl File is stored in  SFTP server and in .tar.gz. Can i used without extraction?

Comment: @Hacker Your comment is as vague as the question. What is "use"?

Comment: @MosamPrajapati What is "list file"? Why do you keep using singular? Is there only a **single** file in the archive and you need to find out its name?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  Can you elaborate what you need in question?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i  get file name from the server but the question that the file is to big (5 GB) can i access from server without download?

Comment: What is **access**? What do you **want to do** with the archive? That's what we need to know! **Access** or **use** does not mean anything to us!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am connected to SFTP and i want to read the file name's of the subfile  which are located in the tar. For e.g : I am getting the list of files in terminal. But sftp commands does not the provide the mechanism to tar based commands on SFTP terminal. So i am using PHP to interact with SFTP server. But I am unable to connected to remote directory.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting ["Limitations > Random access" section of Wikipedia "tar" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#Random_access):

> Another weakness of the tar format compared to other archive formats (like DAR or Zip) is that there is no centralized location for the information about the contents of the file (a "table of contents" of sorts). **So to list the names of the files that are in the archive, one must read through the entire archive and look for places where files start.**

- *"read through the entire archive"* - That effectively means downloading whole archive, what you do not want to do.
- *"look for places where files start"* - For that you need a random access to the archive file. While the SFTP protocol allows a random access to a file, your tar is actually in a gzip file. And compressed files, at least the gzip format, do not allow random access.

In my opinion, contrary to the wording of the Wikipedia article, you do not need to "read through the entire archive", you can just skip from one file start to another. What is slightly better. But as long as the .tar is in .gz, it does not really help you in your cause.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the [Php Phar](http://php.net/manual/en/phardata.extractto.php) extension to extract the 5Gb tar.gz file. After extracting the file you can read the contents of the extracted folder using scandir function.

To automate the process of extracting and listing files, you can use the [SSHPass](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/) utility. You can run the SSHPass from Php using exec function. The output of the exec function should show the list of files.

Comment: OP does not want to download the 5GB archive.

Comment: They dont need to download the archive. The SSHPass allows remote login  from script. The archive is extracted on the server. The archive can be extracted using tar -xvzf command. Php Phar is not needed

Comment: While this is a possible workaround, the question is about SFTP. OP does not mention if they have a shell access to the server.